# dbutils.widgets.dropdown() issue: com.databricks.dbutils_v1.TooManyDefaultChoices: Too many default choices (1116). Limit is 1024

Tags: databricks

While running dbutils.widgets.dropdown(), I face the following issue: com.databricks.dbutils_v1.TooManyDefaultChoices: Too many default choices (1116). Limit is 1024. I searched but could not find an answer, how to change the default value. For sure, I have more than 1024 unique values. Please try to provide the answers. Thanks in advance. Regards, Chaitanya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way of changing the maximum number of choices, because it may negatively impact browser performance. There's no other solution than reducing the number of choices.